# Passing value in an array in webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-2.0

This is my code in the webservice

```
private object[] _myObjectVariableList = new object[7];

public object[] MyObjectVariableList
{
    get { return _myObjectVariableList; }
    set { _myObjectVariableList = value; }
}
```

and when I pass a value to it using

```
 AuditTrail auditclass = new AuditTrail();
 auditclass.MyObjectVariableList[indexCounter] = myTextBox.Text;
```

I receive an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I really do not know whats happening

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize  the list in client side

```
AuditTrail auditclass = new AuditTrail(); 

auditclass.MyObjectVariableList = new object[7];
```

or in service class constructor initialize the property value

```
public class AuditTrail 
{
    private object[] _myObjectVariableList;

    public object[] MyObjectVariableList
    {
        get { return _myObjectVariableList; }
        set { _myObjectVariableList = value; }
    }
    public AuditTrail()
    {
        MyObjectVariableList= new object[7];
    }
}
```